# How to remove issues in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wrote a small jQuery application recently to practise the language and got some feedback which criticised it in the following:

1. you don't use any message passing in your functions,
2. you had hard coded values for some of your data (eg: the colours),
3. you had initalisation code embedded rather than extracted out into a separate JSON file

But I dont really understand what they mean, and how I remove these issues.

Can anyone give me rough examples of them, and the correct approach?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Its really hard to understand exactly what you are asking here.  If there are some bugs in your application you should address them.  If you don't understand what these people are talking about - ask them!  This is not a good type of question for our Q&A format.  Questions here need to be more specific than this. The answer to your question in its current form is - **debug your application to remove issues...**

Comment: Can we see your code? so as to better enable us to provide some constructive feedback?

Comment: It's very hard to say anything without seeing the code. Some of those things don't sound too serious anyway, depending on the app of course. Also, they don't sound like problems that need removed but features that need added.

Comment: lol! you don't say what you have tried and directly jump upon the problems?

Comment: I think you should split this into 3 questions specific to your posted feedback with example code.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can either show some code so we can point out the problems that you are asking...or you can go do a little Google-sleuthing and find out what these terms mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Probably he suggested that you are only using global variables, and no functions with parameters. That can be a choice, but I'd say it doesn't matter in smaller web applications.
2. Hardcoded static data can be irritating when you want to change it. If you decide that the color must me more bluish than it is now, you have to find and replace every single place where you used that color. Using a variable for that color, you only have to change something once, and you avoid hard-to-find bugs
3. Also practical reasons. Instead of editing the entire JavaScript file, you only have to change the small init file. This can be handy for testing purposes, or in big projects.